# Pandas - How to repeat axvline through each graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

New to pandas/python and trying to figure out how to get a repeating line throughout all of my graphs to pin point and exact location, my code is working and I have the line showing for one therefore I would imagine I need to loop through all of them, but I simply don't know how to do it.

Code is following:

```
crimeDataBelfastMonthByType = crimeData[['Ward Name','Month']]
crimeDataBelfastMonthByType = pd.DataFrame({'count' : crimeDataBelfastMonthByType.groupby([ "Ward Name", "Month"] ).size()}).reset_index()
fig3 = pd.pivot_table(crimeDataBelfastMonthByType, values='count', index=['Month'], columns=['Ward Name'], fill_value=0)
fig3.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(fig2.index)
fig3.plot(figsize=(30, 30), subplots=True, layout=(-1, 6), sharex=False, sharey=False);
plt.axvline(x = ['2016-01'], color='red',linestyle='--');
```

Graph is the following:
[image: Graphs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataFrame.plot()` method returns as its first argument a numpy array of all the matplotlib subplot axes in the resulting figure.

**Solution:** save the axis array, loop through it, and call `ax.axvline()` on each subplot.

```
# Unchanged lines from your example
crimeDataBelfastMonthByType = crimeData[['Ward Name','Month']]
crimeDataBelfastMonthByType = pd.DataFrame({'count' : crimeDataBelfastMonthByType.groupby([ "Ward Name", "Month"] ).size()}).reset_index()
fig3 = pd.pivot_table(crimeDataBelfastMonthByType, values='count', index=['Month'], columns=['Ward Name'], fill_value=0)
fig3.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(fig2.index)

# Modified lines below
axarr = fig3.plot(figsize=(30, 30), subplots=True, layout=(-1, 6), sharex=False, sharey=False);
for ax in axarr.flat:
    ax.axvline(x = ['2016-01'], color='red',linestyle='--');
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you so much for replying but I still seem to be getting an error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'axvline'

Comment: You need to flatten `axarr`, i.e. `for ax in axarr.flat:`